# why mapView don't showUserLocation immediately, print some errors , after about 3 mintues, it call 'didUpdateUserLocation'

Tags: ios, swift, location, mkmapview, ios9

When I lanuch my app , it will display a mapView with user's location, but the mapView don't showUserLocation immediately, print some errors , after about 3 mintues, it call 'didUpdateUserLocation', then it show user's location. About a few minutes it locate successfully, before success it located always fail.

My code work fine in iOS7 but have this problem in iOS9, I don't konw why.

I call the `self.locationManger.startUpdatingLocation()` in `viewDidLoad()`.

This is my mapView

```
 lazy var mapView: MKMapView = {
    var tempMapView = MKMapView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    tempMapView.mapType = MKMapType.Standard
    tempMapView.showsUserLocation = true
    tempMapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingMode.Follow
    tempMapView.delegate = self
    return tempMapView
    }()
```

Here is the print error

```
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ProtocolBuffer/ProtocolBuffer-242/Runtime/PBRequester.m:807 server (https://gsp13-cn.ls.apple.com/localshift) returned error: 504
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ProtocolBuffer/ProtocolBuffer-242/Runtime/PBRequester.m:807 server (https://gsp13-cn.ls.apple.com/localshift) returned error: 503
```

Comment: For location use CLlocationmanager and call it on ViewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

Call Startupdate location :

```
manager = CLLocationManager()
manager.delegate = self
manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
manager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Also check this : http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/